# Running Rails console in Sandbox mode in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

Is it a good practice running rails console in `sandbox` mode in prod?

I'm looking for a good way to test things on the production server. `rails console --sandbox` seems like a good option: I can test whatever I need without any worry to affect the production.

After talking to other programmers, they are saying that the `sandbox` transactions might block other requests. That's why it's better to do `rails console` and just be careful with whatever you're doing.

The only piece of information that I found is [Rails Command Line Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-console). And of course there is nothing about how `sandbox` works and whatnot. Do you think that's ok to run `rails console --sandbox` on the prod? Why? Why not?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a very good idea no. Why do you need to test something like this in production?

Comment: For example, when you're using an external email service with the templates stored on that service. Using console to make sure that the right data is sent out, received, and finally the email is sent out to the destination.
Ideally, you never touch production but sometimes you just need to run simple tests quickly and using console is handy for that.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on having a `staging` environment, a middle step between development and production. Playing around with production environments can be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Following command is used to run rails console in sandbox mode in production environment

```
 RAILS_ENV=production rails c --sandbox
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: It is not a good practice.** Rolling back the db transactions does not ensure you'll end up in the initial system state.

Some reasons:

- **Your database rows are fully locked**, during this process, if you hold a record, other real-time services of your system won't be able to change it.
- You might end up running code that triggers non-rollbackable code. Sending an email, or calling an external service.